# Add Explnation Text under Form Toggle in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to replicate a common view that I've seen in the iPhone settings where you can see some settings field and underneath it, there's an explanation text:

[image]

I can't find a way to add the explanation text below and make it look neat like Apple are doing:

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @State private var someBool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle("I am a toggle", isOn: $someBool)
            Text("This is not formatted well :(")
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Some form"))
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
    
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use section footer for that, like

```
    Form {
        Section {
            Toggle("I am a toggle", isOn: $someBool)
        } footer: {
            Text("This is not formatted well :(")   // << here !!
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
    }
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Comment: Boom. I knew there was a property just for this. Works like a charm, thank you! :)